# Why user permissions are not showing in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am creating a group, added permissions to that group and assigning that group to a user (as shown in below code):

```
new_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=grp_name)
permission_obj = Permission.objects.get(name=permission)
new_group.permissions.add(permission_obj)
user.groups.add(new_group)
```

This code works properly but in admin interface the 'user permissions' section is not showing added group permissions

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign permissions using a group, they do not show in the "User Permissions" section. That section is only for assigning individual permissions to one user, rather than using groups which are better suited to applying multiple permissions to many users.

Comment: I want to assign the permissions(that are added to group) to a user. How to do that?

Comment: You've already done it! If you assign permissions to a group, then that group to a user that user then has all of the permissions of that group.  The "User Permissions" section is really for adding something extra. Lets say you have a group that has permissions 1,2,3,4 and you add that to 5 users, for the 6th user you want them to have permissions 1,2,3,4,5 so what you'd do is add the group to them (to get 1,2,3,4) and then in the "User Permsissions" table just add 5, they'll then have all the permissions from the group plus the extra one

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks a lot for the explanation.